# one item in combobox is bold other are not bold - how to make it?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, combobox

Good day!
I have a combobox in a silverliht application

```
<ComboBox  x:Name="cbCities" Width="500" Height="24"/>
```

and bind to it a list of items of City class.
The items of City class have a property *isCapital*
There is an only one or no any items with *isCapital = true* in the list
I want to make the item with *isCapital = true* to be bold in the combobox, and other items not ot be bold.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I think is either add FontWeigth property to your City class or even better to create Inherited class CityUI where you will store all your visual related things. And then DataBind to this property in DataTemplate.

```
public partial class City
{
        public FontWeight FontWeight
        {
            get
            {
                if (isCapital) return FontWeights.Bold;
                return FontWeights.Normal;
            }
        }
}

<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock FontWeight="{Binding Path=FontWeight}" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```